# why I can't connect to the computer from my mobile phone?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, sockets, httpserver

I'm developing an http file server using the python package http.server
using that code :

```
import http.server
import socketserver
import socket

Host = socket.gethostname()
IpAdr = socket.gethostbyname(Host)

PORT = 8000

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer((IpAdr, PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at", IpAdr,':',PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

I'm able to connect from another computer on the LAN

but when trying to connect from a mobile device that is connected to the same network
I get a message on the browser that the link is unreachable

when trying the same python script using http.server package on a different computer on the same network it works fine and I'm able to connect from a mobile device

I'm working on windows 10 operating system

any help on what could be the problem

Comment: @DiegoVinícius no I'm using the machine IP address

Comment: dunno if that will make the diference, but when i tried to run things on my local machine and use on myphone, i must add my local ip and port instead of localhost and port

Comment: @DiegoVinícius Didn't help!

Comment: Paste your code to connect to your server

Comment: @DiegoVinícius Sorry! but what fo you mean by past your code to connect to your server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208990/discussion-between-mosa-abbas-and-diego-vinicius).

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a programming question.

Comment: This likely isn't related to python at all, but the configuration of your network and hosts. Does your server host have a firewall? Is the port 8000 open? Can you reach the host via ``ping`` or ``telnet``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I can reach to the host vie ping from another computer and the port is open but I can't connect from my mobile phone